# Orientation of a BMP file: upright or upside-down?

Tags: bmp, file-format

I'm working on a program to resize a BMP file and store it in a new file. I noticed that some BMPs are stored totally upside-down while others are just stored upright. So I made two solutions to handle both cases. My question is How to know if the BMP is stored upright or upside-down beforehand? So that I can decide which solution to use instead of trying both solutions with every BMP!

Comment: what has this to do with end of file? If BMPs are stored differently (I am surpised a bit), then I would figure there should be a flag or some metadata at the beginning of the file that may tell you this.

Comment: @KamiKaze I thought that maybe one way to know if the BMP is stored upright or upside-down is to look for the EOF, and if it's at the right bottom corner of the image this means it's stored upright, and if it's at the right top corner, this means it's stored upside-down. But after all this thinking I think it was a way easier than this. Thanks to vmt he mentioned that I can easily decide the orientation with the sign of the bi.biHeight (negative or positive).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer lies within the BITMAPINFOHEADER-structure.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318229(v=vs.85).aspx

> For uncompressed RGB bitmaps, if biHeight is positive, the bitmap is a bottom-up DIB with the origin at the lower left corner. If biHeight is negative, the bitmap is a top-down DIB with the origin at the upper left corner.

Comment: Welcome to SO. really nice first answer.

Comment: Long time lurker, first time poster. The usual. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, I always upvote questions that I answer. I figure that if it's worth answering, then it's worth a vote.

Comment: @user3386109 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359703/why-dont-questions-get-that-much-upvote-love

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre An interesting read, your answer needs to be closer to the top :)

Comment: thanks. Funny how the question got a lot of upvotes but the answer didn't :) that's why discussion exists I guess.